# Angular load component on page refresh

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

In app.module.ts I use APP_INITIALIZER to call my initialiser service (ApplicationInitialiserService).
This loads data from an api and creates routes dynamically.
All these routes target a child component.

When I click the router links to navigate this initialises the targeted component and everything loads fine.

But when I refresh the page it does not load up this child component.

Maybe I need to detect a page refresh and load in the child component?
Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Test code -
if you go to https://ivw5j6.csb.app/ and click the routerLink to /test it loads and shows "page works"
But if you refresh https://ivw5j6.csb.app/test the page component does not load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `this.router.initialNavigation();` in your service after adding routes